# How to stop windows 10 action center from notifying me whenever I receive an email?

Tags: windows, windows-10, email, action-center

I linked gmail and live with the mail app (not outlook) in windows 10, I want the action center to stop notifying me whenever I get a new email because I have a gmail checker and I don't care about emails I receive on my live mail.

How to stop windows 10 action center from notifying me whenever I receive an email? If possible, I'd like to stop notification from gmail and live mail but not other email accounts, if that's not possible, then I'd like to stop all email notifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click the Settings icon (gear symbol) in the Mail App, you will see a Notifications option. You can configure how notifications are handled for each email account.